Could propositions that have only universal quantifiers be interpreted as specifying domains of discourse?
Could propositions that have only universal quantifiers be interpreted as specifying domains of discourse? I ask because of the following:

Let $P(x)$ signify at the pub
Let $D(x)$ signify is drinking
$\exists x\left(P\left(x\right)\rightarrow D\left(x\right)\right)\leftrightarrow\left(\forall x\left(P\left(x\right)\right)\rightarrow\exists x\left(D\left(x\right)\right)\right)$ is valid in FOL
$\left(\forall x\left(P\left(x\right)\right)\rightarrow\exists x\left(D\left(x\right)\right)\right)$ could be interpreted as the following: If the domain of discourse is that of all people in a pub, then at least one person is drinking.


Every predicateogic formula must be interpreted specifying a domain of discourse.

The truth value of a formula depends on the intepretation: consider e,g. $\exists x (x < 0)$ that is false in $\mathbb N$ but is true in $\mathbb Q$.

IMO, the correct reading of $∀xP(x)→∃xD(x)$ - with the key above - is: "If everyone is at the pub, then at least someone is drinking" where we have aasumed as universe the colelction of all person (in the world, in the town,...) The key above suggests "human beings" and not e.g. numbers as elements of the domain, but does not restrict the domain to some specific population.

On the Drinkers Paradox, see https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/the-drinkers-paradox/

Note that it is trivial to prove: $\exists a: \neg D(a) \implies \exists a:[D(a) \implies Q]$ for any unary predicate $D$ and proposition $Q$.

Also, why can't we have subdomains of discourse?

Though is it may be a convenient shortcut, in most rigorous, mathematical proofs, there is no implicit assumption of the existence of an overarching, non-empty domain of discourse, i.e. from $\forall x:  P(x)$ alone, it cannot be inferred that $\exists(x): P(x)$.

In the Drinkers Paradox, it turns out that if we make the reasonable assumption that there exists even a single non-drinker anywhere, i.e. $\exists x: \neg D(x)$, then we can infer that $\exists x:[D(x) \implies Q]$ for ANY proposition $Q$ whatsoever, be it true or false. Similarly, if there exists even a single thing not in the pub, i.e. $\exists x: \neg P(x)$, then we can infer that $\exists x:[P(x) \implies Q]$

@AUTISTINC  I have already replied to the question: I am a bit disappointed it was closed since the question per se is important for beginners (<<what is the "domain of discourse"?>>), though I'd agree it is not well presented: in fact, your 3 is not a validity (I think), and (surely) none of those represent the Drinker's paradox...

Technically, no: $\forall x, p(x)$ reads "for all $x$ in the universe of discourse, $p(x)$ holds", similarly, $\exists x, p(x)$ reads "exists $x$ in the universe of discourse s.t. $p(x)$ holds".  Namely, the universe of discourse, whether explicit or implicit, is just all $x$'s we can possibly talk about: i.e. quantify over.
For example, in set theory all we can talk (reason, write statements) about is "sets" and nothing but "sets".  In fact, the notation $\forall x \in S, p$ is short-hand for $\forall x, x \in S \to p$, where the quantifier is ranging over all possible sets (i.e. all that are realizable in the specific system).
That said, a more informal notion of "universe of discourse" may be established by a problem setting, e.g. "(all men of) the island" in the Barber's paradox, or "(all people in) a pub" in the Drinker's, but that is a "universe of discourse" only informally and would rather correspond to a specific collection (or type) in the formal system that we are going to restrict our quantifications over.
